# How do I change CSS for before or after of li when one of li is selected?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

```
<li><span class="item-label">1</span><li>
<li><span class="item-label">2</span><li>
<li class="selected"><span class="item-label">3</span><li>
<li><span class="item-label">4</span><li>
<li><span class="item-label">5</span><li>
```

Hi everyone

I want to ask how I can change CSS for before or after of li when one of li is selected.

For example, If I select 3, I need to change the CSS for 2 and 4.

Thanks your answer.

Comment: There are no :after or :before pseudo classes, so the only way to select for 2 or 4 is to follow Stephen's advice, or give 2 and 4 classes or ids themselves.

Comment: Why would you want to change the css for both 2 and 4 when you select 3?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nth-child.

Ex :

li:nth-child(3):hover li:nth-child(2), li:nth-child(4) {

color:red;

}

That is pure css, you mean selected with jquery, you can basically do the same thing.

Comment: What do you mean "basically the same thing?" Also, this wont work if OP has other lists on his page.

Comment: This isn't what OP is asking. He wants to select the previous and next elements of the li selected.

Comment: Using nth-child would be really hard coding it, he could do it that way. Jquery does work with nth-child, he could do it that way.

Comment: the 3 is just a example. maybe I choose 4, and I need to change the CSS of 3 and 5.

I know this is wrong. 
li.selected:nth-child(-1) .item-label{
 border-bottom:3px solid #000;
}

Comment: It would have to be more dynamic then what I wrote of course. If you can use jquery on this project, I think it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

With CSS, I believe you can choose the next list item by doing .select + li, but I don't know of a great way to select the previous with CSS only.

I would accomplish this with mooTools...

document.getElement('.select + li').setStyles({ border: '1px solid #000' });

document.getElement('.select !+ li').setStyles({ border: '1px solid #000' });

Which will style the previous and next list item surrounding your .select class.

Comment: I don't if I allow use jQuery in this project. The project I am working use mootools, but don't know any mootools yet.

Comment: Looks like in mootools it would be something like this...

document.getElement('.select + li') // Selects Next
document.getElement('.select !+ li') // Selects previous

Comment: You can chain that with .setStyles({
    border: '1px solid #000',
    width: 300,
    height: 400
});

Comment: Thank you. I will try to figure out.

Comment: I adjusted my answer for mooTools. Give it a try.

Comment: Thank you. but I still don't understand how to write if I need make changes for previous and next .item-label when li is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$('#menu li').click(function() 
{
    $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Now you create a style for example:

```
#menu .active
{
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Using this method, only clicked `li` link will have `class:active` which will then be linked with the style and the `class:active` will be removed from the other `li` link.

Here's a working demo: [Change active class](http://jsfiddle.net/xTWqT/2/).

Hope this helps :)